# Issue load pytorch model (model.pt) from url _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'

Tags: pytorch, load, google-colaboratory

I am loading my model in Google Colab from URL (model hosted in Bucket in google cloud)

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/hub.py", line 595, in load_state_dict_from_url
    return torch.load(cached_file, map_location=map_location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 713, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 920, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.
```

any idea what is wrong?